# Apache not starting in MAMP (but MySQL working) in Windows 10

Tags: mamp

Apache not starting in MAMP (but MySQL working) in Windows 10. MAMP Version 4.1.1.18915.

[image: apache_error]

[image: MAMP screenshot]

Comment: All of those “unclean shutdown” means you most likely force quit prior to this happening. I would recommend a complete reboot of Windows and trying again.

Comment: @JakeGould I did clean complete reboot multiple times and also reinstalled MAMP, But sitll i am facing same problem

Answer (score 6):

@vishal I've encountered the same issue. The only thing that is currently solving the issue for me is changing the php version in MAMP preferences. Try it out!

In the MAMP menu there's a link to preferences. When you click it you'll find the options to change ports, php, web server etc. There's a dropdown menu in the PHP section to change the version. [Here's a screenshot](https://share.getcloudapp.com/L1uko5XG)

Comment: How does one do that?

Comment: @music2myear In the MAMP menu there's a link to preferences. When you click it you'll find the options to change ports, php, web server etc. There's a dropdown menu in the PHP section to change the version. Here's a screenshot: https://share.getcloudapp.com/L1uko5XG

Comment: That information should be in the body of your answer to make it better. Use the edit button to do this.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the heads up for making the answer better and useful.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for making your answer better. The more info in the answer, the better it is, and the more up votes you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
apache -k shutdown
```

Or:

```
apache -k restart
```

At Windows command line.

You could also tipe at Windows Explorer `services.msc` and stop/restart `Apache.24` service.

But the first two options at the command line should work like a charm.

Comment: Are you sure that those commands would work with MAMP? In macOS the whole LAMP stack is self-contained within the MAMP application. So generic start/stop commands don’t really work the same way in that case.